# Pascals Identity Question, $n-1 \choose k-1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations, binomial-coefficients

The idea behind pascals identity is $\displaystyle \binom n k = \binom {n-1}k + \binom{n-1}{k-1}$.

I understand that we're splitting up the number of $k$ element sets into the number of $k$ element sets which include $n$ and the number of $k$ element sets which don't include $n$.
$n-1 \choose k$ makes sense to me, however $n-1 \choose k-1$ doesn't make sense, how this would determine the number of $k$ element subsets which include $n$, any explanations would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us imagine a kingdom of $n$ people, and one person is the king. Let us now try to choose $k$ people from the kingdom. We may do it in one of two ways: either the king is chosen or he is not. If we do not choose the king, we, therefore, choose $k$ people from $n-1$ people, as the king remains unchosen. However, if the king is chosen, we need yet to choose $k-1$ people from the remaining $n-1$ people. As the two cases were separate, we achieve that we can choose $k$ people from $n$ people as the sum:
$$\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n-1}{k}+\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$